# using replicate central limit t

Tags: r, replicate

doing a course and the following is the question.

```
library(downloader)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleMiceWeights.csv"
filename <- "femaleMiceWeights.csv"
if(!file.exists("femaleMiceWeights.csv")) download(url,destfile=filename)
dat <- read.csv(filename)
```

Suppose we are interested in the proportion of times we see a 6 when rolling n=100 die. This is a random variable which we can simulate with x=sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE) and the proportion we are interested in can be expressed as an average: mean(x==6). Because the die rolls are independent, the CLT applies.

We want to roll n dice 10,000 times and keep these proportions. This random variable (proportion of 6s) has mean p=1/6 and variance p*(1-p)/n. So according to CLT z = (mean(x==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n) should be normal with mean 0 and SD 1. Set the seed to 1, then use replicate to perform the simulation, and report what proportion of times z was larger than 2 in absolute value (CLT says it should be about 0.05).

So i wrote the following :

```
    set.seed(1)
    n<-10000
    p<-1/6
    a<-replicate(n, {
      x=sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE)
      z<-(mean(x==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)

    })
> mean(abs(a)>2)
[1] 0.0472
```

So its wrong but pretty close, anyone see where i went wrong ?

Comment: I would say you are nearly perfect. According to CLT, with high number of observations you reach nearly a normal distribution but it does not define what the large number is. It could be possible that 10000 replications is still not enough. In other words, you converge towards a normal distribution but the convergence points are not defined.

Comment: you can do    `mean(abs(a)>qnorm(0.975))`  to get   0.0513 it's a bit better (0.05055  with `n<- 20000)`

Comment: OH i think you misunderstood... my answer is marked wrong :( that is why i asked.. so i must have done something wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My answer is marked wrong :( that is why i asked.. so i must have done something wrong :(

Looks like you are doing a homework or something, then you were marked wrong, because your code does not really do what your question asks:

> We want to roll n dice 10,000 times and keep these proportions

This is the correct version; don't put `n` inside `sample()`.

```
set.seed(1); n <- 10000; p <- 1/6
a <- replicate(n, (mean(sample(1:6, 10000, replace=TRUE)==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/10000))
```

---

Also, you are not comparing with the right thing.

> CLT says it should be about 0.05

No! The theoretic quantity you need compare with is `2 * pnorm(-2)`, which is `0.04550026`. The corresponding quantile for `0.05` is `-qnorm(0.025)` which is `1.96` not `2`.

Let's check what `mean(abs(a) > 2)` gives.

- With `n = 10000` and `set.seed(1)`, you get `0.0472`, already close to true value;
- With `n = 20000` and `set.seed(1)`, you get `0.04565`, even closer!

Comment: Hmm if i used n=10000 i get exactly the 0.0472 like you, so how can mine be wrong ?

Comment: I appreciate that.. and i was wrong :) i am still befuddled why my answer gets marked wrong (only the numer is requested, not the code) :(

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with the almost the same code:

```
set.seed(1); n <- 10000; p <- 1/6
a <- replicate(n, (mean(sample(1:6, 100, replace=TRUE)==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/100))
```

Notice that the problem is the formulation of the question...you want to take 100 samples each time but do it 10000. 0.0424 is the correct answer.